# Filter Google Cloud Logs to logs at a certain hour of the day

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'd like to write a query that filters logs to only a particular hour of the day. This should retrieve logs at the same hour every day. For example, lets say the hour is 4pm / 16:00. It should retrieve logs with timestamp values:

- 2023-04-20T16:00:00Z
- 2023-04-20T16:12:34Z
- 2023-04-21T16:00:00Z
- 3004-01-01T16:00:00Z

I've tried using regex-based matching, but get an error "Field is of incorrect type. Regular expression matches can only be performed against string-compatible fields.":

```
timestamp=~"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT16:\d\d:\d\d(\.\d+)?Z"
```

I've also tried accessing properties on this object, but that results in the error "Field 'timestamp' cannot have members.":

```
timestamp.hour=16
```

Is there some other way to filter logs by hour of day?

Answer (score 2):

You can set [specific limits on the date and time](https://%E2%80%8Bhttps://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#search_by_time) of log entries to show.

the preview displays exactly the log entries in the indicated 60-minute period and you won't be able to scroll outside of that date range:

```
timestamp >= "2023-01-18T16:00:00Z"
timestamp <= "2023-01-18T16:59:59Z"
```

Sample Filter for January 18 16:00:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.totalBilledBytes>"0"
timestamp >= "2023-01-18T16:00:00Z"
timestamp <= "2023-01-18T216:59:59Z"
```

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse! Is it possible to do this for the same say 60-minute period every day, without having loads of OR clauses?

e.g. equivalent to:

```
(timestamp >= "2023-01-18T16:00:00Z" AND timestamp <= "2023-01-18T16:59:59Z")
OR (timestamp >= "2023-01-19T16:00:00Z" AND timestamp <= "2023-01-19T16:59:59Z")
OR (timestamp >= "2023-01-20T16:00:00Z" AND timestamp <= "2023-01-20T16:59:59Z")
OR (timestamp >= "2023-01-21T16:00:00Z" AND timestamp <= "2023-01-21T16:59:59Z")
...
```